# What variety of plum tree do I have?

Tags: identification, trees, plums

I bought house in central Oklahoma 4 years ago. It has a plum tree that sits alone in front yard. 2 years ago it produced the best plums I've ever had but none since. I've tried to find out why which brings me here, as I'm hoping to get help identifying it. It's approx 15 feet tall with green leaves, brownish red bark that's got spots and vein-like lines. The leaf stalk is light green. Also the leaves are simple, ovate, with toothed margins not overly sharp.

Comment: Please add a photograph of the tree and some close-ups of the leaves, flowers, bark, etc.

Comment: Because many plum cultivars are very similar in appearance, it would help a lot for you to describe the fruit (color, size, firmness, sweetness, etc.).

Comment: Is it flowering and just failing to produce fruit, or is it not even flowering? Some plums are a little temperamental, like the green gage, and won't produce every year. It'd be hard to know if that is the issue, though, without seeing the fruit.

Answer (score 0):

You said your tree is in your front yard. Is it near or in a lawn? It might be that you've been fertilizing your tree with lawn fertilizer. The high nitrogen for lawns might be suppressing reproductive growth.

Two years ago you had plums. What happened last year? Have you done extensive pruning, fertilized or sprayed with anything...?

Identifying a plum and its variety will be tough. We need to have pictures of buds, leaves, and bark, but mainly the flowers and fruit. Do any of your neighbors have the same tree?